# What is the number of tokens in the following code snippet?

Tags: compilation, lexical-analysis

`printf` `(` `"Some string here"` `,` `++` `i` `++` `&&` `&` `i` `*` `*` `*` `a` `)` `;`

I am confused, how to count the number of tokens for this code snippet. Basically, I am not getting how `&&&` and `***` will be counted.

I think `&&` is one token and & is one, while, `***` are total 3 tokens, but i am not sure that it is right or not.

I have edited the code with whitespaces to seperate tokens .

Can someone explain with any technique, so that i can apply for any code snippet?

Any help will be greatly appreciated !!

Comment: @WeatherVane, edited !! Can you please check now

Comment: How is `a` declared?

Comment: Why does it matter how `a` is declared? The question is about tokenizing. `a` is one token.

Comment: But the compiler doesn't know that at the tokenizing stage. After tokenization it then might determine that there's an error that gets reported, but it doesn't matter when it's tokenized.

Comment: This already a complete and valid program from the point of view of lexical analysis.  It's C semantics where it all fails one way or another.

Comment: @aschepler, It has 11 lexemes , right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C tokenization is "greedy" - it attempts to build the longest legal token first.  See the [online C 2011 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), section 6.4.6 (Punctuators) for the list of legal punctuator tokens (`&&`, `++`, etc.).

The sequence `++i++&&&i***a` will be tokenized as `++`, `i`, `++`, `&&`, `&`, `i`, `*`, `*`, `*`, `a`.  It will be *parsed* as `(++(i++)) && ((&i) * (**a))`, which is not a legal expression (the result of `i++` is not an lvalue, so it cannot be the operand of the unary `++` operator).

Comment: Not to mention you can't multiply a pointer value by anything.

Comment: @aschepler: that too.

Comment: @Willturner: I count 10 tokens overall, 6 distinct token values.  Not sure how that maps to lexemes.  At the tokenization stage there's no distinction between pre- and postfix `++` - that comes during syntax analysis.

Comment: @JohnBode, Thanku very much. I got it .

Comment: If it were C++, the expression might be valid, depending on the types of `i` and `a` and the existence of appropriate operator methods.

Comment: @rici: true.  For some reason I thought this was limited to C, but if that's not the case, you're correct.

Comment: Now I see that the [tag:c] was removed by @weathervane, which arguably changed the semantics of the question. My comment was based on what I saw, which was language-agnostic, although I assumed it referred to the C "family", based on the use of pre- and post-increment operators.

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis is correct.  Tokenization in C is greedy, meaning that when `&&&` is encountered, the longest possible token `&&` is scanned first.  There is no `**` token, so each `*` character is its own token.

The tokens are:

1. `printf`
2. `(`
3. `"Some string here"`
4. `,`
5. `++`
6. `i`
7. `++`
8. `&&`
9. `&`
10. `i`
11. `*`
12. `*`
13. `*`
14. `a`
15. `)`
16. `;`

Comment: I'm not sure how you're defining / counting lexemes.

Comment: printf is a lexeme, ++, && are all predefined inside the compiler, hence are called lexemes . Note: i am not talking about distinct lexemes. I am saying total number of lexemes .